# MySQL - Best approach to create multiple write servers across geographical location and sync

Tags: mysql

im building a simple saas and I want to spin up mysql servers with write capability in different geographical location. The idea is to provide fastest possible write access to end users. 
However, these data should be synchronized to a master server. What is the best approach?

- I have check cluster and replication but im not sure if they are even the right setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly complex problem that introduces the need to also handle
conflict detection.

With MySQL Cluster and using MySQL Replication it is possible to
achieve this behaviour.

However the conflict detection can easily become pretty complex.
So you really need to define what conflicts you want to handle
and which you can avoid or ignore.

I am right now starting out to write a chapter in my upcoming book
on MySQL Cluster that handles this exact problem on setting up a
globally distributed database with several master clusters in different
regions.

MySQL/InnoDB replication doesn't support multi-master setups.
MySQL Group Replication isn't intended for geographically distributed
setups.